# SQLAlchemy Generates Wrong SQL (for aliased and self-join)?

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy 0.8 is generating wrong SQL for the following simple self-join --

```
class ScheduledJob(Base):
    Id = Column('Id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    DependentJob1 = Column('DependentJob1', Integer)

DJ1 = aliased(ScheduledJob)
query = dbsession.query(ScheduledJob.Id, DJ1.Id).outerjoin(
        DJ1, ScheduledJob.DependentJob1==DJ1.Id)
print query
```

and prints the wrong SQL --

```
SELECT "ScheduledJob"."Id" AS "ScheduledJob_Id"
FROM "ScheduledJob" LEFT OUTER JOIN "ScheduledJob" AS "ScheduledJob_1" ON
"ScheduledJob"."DependentJob1" = "ScheduledJob"."Id"
```

while it should have been --

```
SELECT "ScheduledJob"."Id" AS "ScheduledJob_Id",
"ScheduledJob_1"."Id" AS "ScheduledJob_1_Id"
FROM "ScheduledJob" LEFT OUTER JOIN "ScheduledJob" AS "ScheduledJob_1" ON
"ScheduledJob"."DependentJob1" = "ScheduledJob_1"."Id"
```

What's more puzzling is that all the standalone aliased/join/self-join tests I tried following SQLAlchemy document all work fine.

What could have gone wrong? Any pointer will be greatly appreciated.

BTW, I'm mapping multiple databases, could it be related to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

cannot reproduce.  test case run on 0.8.2, 0.8.1, 0.8.0, results are correct:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class ScheduledJob(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ScheduledJob'

    Id = Column('Id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    DependentJob1 = Column('DependentJob1', Integer)

session = Session()

DJ1 = aliased(ScheduledJob)
query = session.query(ScheduledJob.Id, DJ1.Id).outerjoin(DJ1, ScheduledJob.DependentJob1==DJ1.Id)
print query
```

output:

```
SELECT "ScheduledJob"."Id" AS "ScheduledJob_Id", "ScheduledJob_1"."Id" AS "ScheduledJob_1_Id" 
FROM "ScheduledJob" LEFT OUTER JOIN "ScheduledJob" AS "ScheduledJob_1" ON "ScheduledJob"."DependentJob1" = "ScheduledJob_1"."Id"
```

I suspect that in your actual application, "DJ1" is not actually an alias of ScheduledJob.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Mike! Not being able to reproduce this mysterious behavior is precisely the reason why I couldn't come up with a complete test showcasing the problem -- Let me invest this entire Sunday to see if I can find more clue. But at least the snippet is a literal extract from the origin code and "DJ1" is actually an alias of ScheduledJob.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by incorrect usage of SQLAlchemy, which mapped multiple tables extending from a same Base and with the same `__tablename__`

Everything works fine once I separated them to different Base --

```
class ScheduledJobMixin(object):
    Id = Column('Id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...

Remote_Base = declarative_base()
class RemoteScheduledJob(ScheduledJobMixin, Remote_Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ScheduledJob'

Base = declarative_base()
class ScheduledJob(ScheduledJobMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ScheduledJob'
```

Comment: many thanks i run into the same problem ;) i need to create on the fly objects `type (...)` and then do a self join on this table by using different `declerative Base` the problem vanished.